# htaccess prevent use of global SSL redirect in chrome

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I have sites which I'm adding SSL for latest compliance, these have protected admin folders, the global root redirect
    #redirect to ssl site

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

causes visitors using a old http: link to admin to reach 404 page as the redirect happens to early.

Iv'e fixed this for firefox by adding a stop rule prior to the global

```
# stop processing for admin
RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
```

and a specific redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co.uk/admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,r=301,L]
```

however in chrome the directory stop fails and the specific redirect ignored, so chrome visitors get a 404 instead of being redirected.

I have tried multiple additions to the global but none work 
    #redirect to ssl site

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin(.*)  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)admin(.*)  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/].*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Why is firefox and chrome behaving differently, I thought it was apache doing the processing, how do I make chrome behave like firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having posted this and despite having searched extensively another post came up and the final answer on that fixed the issue, so the solution has two parts, in the root I added:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin/*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Then in the admin folder:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
  AuthType       Basic
  AuthName      "Authorization Required"
  AuthUserFile   /var/www/vHost/etc/HTTP-Basic-Auth/htaccess-Users
  require       valid-user
</If>
<Else>
  ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Else>
```

However I still don't understand why chrome is behaving differently to firefox for this.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that Firefox behaves differently from Chrome. It is more likely that there is a cached redirect in Chrome which causes it to visit a former redirect target directly without visiting the original URL. This happens if a 301 redirect is used instead of a 302 one since 301 means permanent redirect and the browser will remember this one.

To get rid of this problem you need to clear the browsers cache so that it no longer remembers and uses the no longer valid redirect.

Comment: Thanks, yes I`m aware of this issue and always clear chromes cache before testing, clearing the cache does not help though.

Comment: @Matt: maybe you should have a look at the actual network traffic using the developer tools. There you can see which URL gets actually accessed, which HTTP request send, which response received, if it is a redirect etc.